# How do I place my entire WordPress installation under git control?

Tags: wordpress, git, github, repository, push

How do I place my entire WordPress installation under git control? I am using Github on a Mac computer and I need to push all my work to a remote repository.

Comment: Q1. Is this including the database (backup) ? or you just need to version control the website (WeodPress inyour case) ?

Comment: Q2. do you have ssh access to the installation source (the server) and is git installed on that machine? or you have to download the source and version control it locally?

Comment: git is installed on my machine. I'm using MAMP.

Answer (score 0):

So the process is straight forward, but don't forget to include a dump of the database to your repository.

say you have the WordPress setup on /Users/yourHome/theSite, then:

1. create or copy a backup of the site's DB to /Users/yourHome/theSite/dbdump
2. go to the site folder `cd /Users/yourHome/theSite`
3. Stage everything `git add .`
4. commit them `git commit -m 'Your commit message`
5. set the repository's remote to where you have to push `git remote set-url origin https://example.com/remote/sample.git`
6. and finally push `git push -u origin master`

please note I'm assuming you already have git repo on the site location. otherwise you need to initiate on in the location before the step 2. lest say as step 1.5 :) `git init`

so after having the db back up ready, you have to:

```sh
cp -rf the/db/backup/* /Users/yourHome/theSite/dbdump/
cd /Users/yourHome/theSite/dbdump
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'Your commit message'
git remote set-url origin https://example.com/remote/sample.git
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: What if the site isn't live. Do I still have a database to backup?

Comment: My wordpress folder is still under Mamp under my Applications.

Comment: if you can see a wordpress site (even the default template) then the database has been setup for you and it contains some settings. if you didnt set anything in the site e.g. the site's tile or if you are happy to set them again then you don't need to include the DB

Comment: the location is not important for your versioning as far as you can get into that folder and initiate a git repository , command like or any GUI :) if you prefer GUIs give [Source Tree](https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview?_mid=e0734c30de09bb01fe8ee8625dc35ca4&gclid=Cj0KEQjwhuqrBRCFuPz4ipOx5JIBEiQAZJ7F-s6FWOhCpmtSHviS5QnI1VbU7mrZIDe1FIqraTd1fR4aAuxn8P8HAQ) a try

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I recently created this same site and did something to destroy all of the files, and had to redo everything, so now I'm very nervous to do anything to it that I don't already know! I appreciate your help!

Comment: If you are moving the database, and have the local at `http://localmamp` and are going to `http://example.com`, you will break the live copy of the site because you have not changed URLs in the database. git doesn't automatically change URLs in the database for you.

Comment: @TaylorMarieTraverse: use https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ or you will break everything. Do not do a find/replace in a database text dump, either; that will break serialized data.

Comment: @markratledge,  i like your input and hence the **up-vote** for both of your comments, **BUT**  please don't forget the question wasn't about to **transferring** the site from one location to another, it was simply to **version control** it.

Comment: @Ali: version control in WordPress *includes* the database.

Comment: @markratledge, defiantly, thats why we include them (DBs). but still it doesn't remove the difference between transferring and version controlling. you can version your site (including the database) without having any issue with the defined urls. the problem you are addressing only occurs when you making changes on the site access url (even not just by relocating a website by keeping the same domain)

Comment: @Ali: You're wrong; any text or content changes in WordPress are in the database, not in static files.

Comment: :D @markratledge, did i mention anything that made you believe I'm saying a CMS holding the content statically? i repeat again, thats why we include the data base to version the content as well as the application and of its assets. Now, when **and if** it comes the time you need to change the site address i.e. moving it from your local machine with no FQD to a public host and domain then we eed to consider your very useful point :) otherwise i can keep versioning my site (including DB) locally without any issue.